How can a DDR5-6000 RAM module with 36-36-36-76 perform worse than one with 38-38-38-78?
From some benchmarking I've seen on tomshardware.com I can see these 2 results (amongst others).
TeamGroup T-Force Vulcanα  - scoring 3429.27 (DDR5-6000 38-38-38-78, 1.25V)
G.Skill Trident Z5 RGB     - scoring 3424.05 (DDR5-6000 36-36-36-76, 1.30V)

I assume these were tested in the same manner on the same kit, so how can the one with the lower latency score slightly less?
Performance-wise is there something other than latency that I should be considering?
